# Changing slidesToShow slick property when $(window).resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Here is my slick slider:

```
            var informations_panel = document.querySelector("#block-views-block-wazne-informacje-strona-glowna-block-1 > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.view-content");
            $(informations_panel).slick({
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 5000,
                arrows: true,
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            });
```

Is there a way to change the `slidesToShow` property when user resizes window? With $(window).resize(), something like:

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var informations_panel = document.querySelector("#block-views-block-wazne-informacje-strona-glowna-block-1 > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.view-content");
        if ($(window).width() < 992) {
            $(informations_panel).slick({
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 5000,
                arrows: true,
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            });
        }
    });
```

This solution makes error that I cannot again initialize slick on the same element. I want only to change property `slidesToShow` from 2 to 1 when width of window is bigger than 992px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "breakpoint" in "responsive" attribute when you initialize your slider.
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ This link should be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`slickSetOption`](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var informations_panel = document.querySelector("#block-views-block-wazne-informacje-strona-glowna-block-1 > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.view-content");
  if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    $(informations_panel).slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', 1);
  }
});
```